# Удаление файлов из массива по заданной маске расширения массива?

Tags: php

Всем доброго дня. Давно не писал на PHP, проекту более 10 лет, вот занялся кое что переделать, есть прстая форма мультизагрузки, есть массив расширений, запрещенных к загрузке. Задача, как на основе этого массива с расширениями, получить полные имена файлов и удалить их из общего массива? Накидал пример, что смог, но что-то не очень:

```
$arr = $_FILES['xtt']['name'];
$deny = array('php');
foreach ($arr as $file) {
foreach ($deny as $ext) {
    echo 'файлы: '.$file.'<br>';
    echo 'расширения: '.pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION).'<br><br>';
if (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == $ext) {
$del = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME).'.'.pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
unset($arr[$del]);
}}}
```

Поделитесь примером, как это лучше реализовать, имеено по задаче? Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: В Интернете полно примеров, как вот с [англоязычного SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456113/check-file-extension-in-upload-form-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
$denyftype = array('htm', 'html', 'shtml', 'xml', 'txt', 'sh', 'bash','pl', 'py', 'pyt', 'css', 'js', 'asp', 'jsp', 'cgi', 'php', 'vbs', 'cmd', 'bat', 'exe', 'dll', 'vxd', 'reg', 'ajax', 'script', 'htaccess', 'htpasswd');

foreach ($_FILES['xtt']['name'] as $key => $name)
{
  $tmp_name = $_FILES['xtt']['tmp_name'][$key];
  $path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES['xtt']['name'][$key]);

   if(in_array($path_parts['extension'], $denyftype))
    {
      if(is_file($tmp_name))
      {
        if(unlink($tmp_name))
        {
          $errors[] = $_FILES['xtt']['name'][$key];
          unset($_FILES['xtt']['name'][$key],
                $_FILES['xtt']['type'][$key],
                $_FILES['xtt']['tmp_name'][$key],
                $_FILES['xtt']['error'][$key],
                $_FILES['xtt']['size'][$key]);
        }
      }
    }
}

//echo '<b>OUT</b><br>';
//print_r($_FILES);

echo 'Файлы '. join(', ',$errors). ' не были загружены, тк запрещены.';
```